# Convergence of Series When a Specific Subseries Converges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I have an infinite sequence $z_n$ $\in \mathbb{C}$ such that the following two conditions are true:

1. $|z_n|\leq n^{-2/3}$.
2. $S_{n^3}$, the sequence of partial sums of the form $\Sigma_{n=1}^{n^3} z_n, \rightarrow 0$.

My intuition is that $\Sigma_{n=1}^{\infty} z_n$ also converges. My logic is this:

In general for two subscripts $k, k+1$, we have that $(k+1)^3 - k^3 = k^3 + 3k^2 + 1 - k^3$ = $3k^2 + 3k + 1$.

Since $0 \leq |z_n| \leq n^{-2/3}$, by the Squeeze Theorem $z_n$ must converge to $0$. If we define $a(n) := 3n^2 + 3n + 1$, then $\forall \epsilon > 0, |z_n| \leq \frac{\epsilon}{a}$ for n sufficiently large, say $\geq N$. Now let us look at the subsequence of partial sums $S_{k^3} : \forall \epsilon > 0, |S_{k^3}| < \frac{\epsilon}{a}$ given that $k^3 \geq K$. Take $L$ := max($N, K$). Then terms $s_l$ of the sequence $S_l$ can be represented in one of two ways:

1. $l = m^3$ for some $m$, so $S_l = S_{m^3} \rightarrow 0$.
2. $l = m^3 + c, c \in \mathbb{N};|S_l| = |S_{m^3} + z_{m^3 + 1} + ... + z_{m^3 + c}|$. But $c \leq a-1$, where $a := a(l)$ (or else $l$ could be represented as $m^3$ for some $m$). So $$|S_l| \leq |S_{m^3} + z_{m^3 + 1} + ... + z_{m^3 + (a-1)}| \leq |S_{m^3}| + |z_{m^3 + 1}| + ... + |z_{m^3 + (a-1)}| \leq \frac{\epsilon}{a} + \frac{\epsilon}{a} + ... \frac{\epsilon}{a} = a(\frac{\epsilon}{a}) = \epsilon,$$ and $S_l \rightarrow 0$.

Is this a valid argument?

Comment: I think you haven't written what you mean. If you just demand that the series $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} z_{n^3}$ converges (whether to $0$ or not is irrelevant), then there is no reason to expect the series $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} z_n$ to converge. If $z_n = n^{-1}$ for every $n$ that is not a cube, the latter series clearly diverges if the first converges. I think you meant that the sequence of cube-indexed partial sums, $$s_{n^3} = \sum_{k = 1}^{n^3} z_k$$ converges. Is that right?

Comment: @DanielFischer If I'm not entirely stupid we don't have $|z_n| \leq n^{-2/3}$ in your example

Comment: @DanielFischer, I did in fact mean the sequence of cube-indexed partial sums, thank you!

Comment: @user159517 For $n \geqslant 1$, we have $n^{-1} \leqslant n^{-2/3}$.

Comment: It still doesn't imply that the full series converges, though you don't need much stronger assumptions. There are $3k(k+1)$ numbers strictly between $k^3$ and $(k+1)^3$. Let the first half of them have the value $\frac{1}{(k+1)^2}$ and the second half have the value $-\frac{1}{(k+1)^2}$. Then the inequality $\lvert z_n\rvert \leqslant n^{-2/3}$ is satisfied, but $$S_{k^3 + \frac{3}{2}k(k+1)} = S_{k^3} + \frac{3k}{2(k+1)}.$$ If you had $\lvert z_n\rvert \in o(n^{-2/3})$, that would suffice.